# AWS S3 signed URL contains AccessKeyId

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to Amazon AWS S3 and I was wondering why my signedURL contains my `AccessKeyId`. Isn't that a security issue, so that other people who have the URL have my accessKey and could potentially get access to my account / bucket?

```
const getURL = async (key) => {

  const params = {
    Bucket: myBucket,
    Key: key, 
    Expires: 60,
  };
  
  const url = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    s3.getSignedUrl("getObject", params, function (err, url) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve(url);
    });
  });

  console.log(url) // signed URL that contains the AccessKeyId and Signature
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AccessKeyId is not a secret. Think of it as a username. The SecretAccessKey is the one that should be kept secret.